# SWFObject and positioning

Tags: html, position, swfobject

How can I specifically position the flash element embeded using SWFObject please?
Moving it's container DIV around with absolute positioning and top and bottom set doesn't seem to work.

Thank you.

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason why this wouldn't work. Can you provide some HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Francisc: Try --

```
<div id="container-div-with-the-positioning-rules">
     <div id="flash-to-be-replaced">
         Your alternate content if the user doesn't have Flash installed
     </div>
</div>
```

**Please note**, this might not be the most elegant solution since it's adding an additional `<div>`, but having had the same problem before, this is basically how I solved it. It might give you something to build on or perhaps some of the other participants on here will have better solutions.

Comment: Thank you stealthyninja! When did you answer, I didn't even see you!

Comment: About seventeen minutes after your posted your question, it seems. As for not seeing me, stealthyninja... ;-)

Comment: @Francisc: Apologies; it seems that whoosh sound wasn't me, it was your joke going over my head. ;-P

Answer (score 5):

I'd vote up or comment on stealthyninja's response, but I can't because I don't have enough rep. But yeah, you have to add another div around the "flash-to-be-replaced" div because SWFObject changes that div to an object tag or something else that CSS can't do anything about.