# Positioning an element embedded in a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, flash

I'm not yet into javascript myself, so I need your help. Situation is that I have a '< script >'-element in an html-document, which embeds a swf-file. Now I want to position said embedded swf. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
        body { margin:0; }
        #game {
            width: 1024px;
            height: 768px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 5%;
            margin-left: -512px;
            border: 1px solid red;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="game">
    <script>
        var flashvars = {
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "",
            wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
        };
        var attributes = {
            id:"projectweb2"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "projectweb2.swf", 
            "altContent", 1024, 768, "10.0.0", 
            "expressInstall.swf", 
            flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
</div>
<div id="altContent">
    <h1>project_web2</h1>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

unfortunately positioning doesn't work that way. Thanks to the red border I can see that the "game"-div is exactly where I want it to be. The embedded swf though is still in the upper left corner and refuses to be moved by the surrounding div and its css-commands.

How can I position the swf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div block `#game`only holds the Javascript block. SWFObject replaces the content in the div `#altContent` (named as second parameter in the function embedSWF) with your SWF. So you should (as you already mentioned yourself in the comments) put the `#altContent` div in the `#game` div like:

```
<div id="game">
    <script>
        var flashvars = {
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "",
            wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
        };
        var attributes = {
            id:"projectweb2"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF(
           "projectweb2.swf", 
            "altContent", 1024, 768, "10.0.0", 
            "expressInstall.swf", 
            flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>

    <div id="altContent">
        <h1>project_web2</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That definitely makes sense, but unfortunately neither of your suggestions did change anything. I guess the real positioning is done somewhere inside "js/swfobject.js", but this file is, alas, not only long but also a totally unformatted, incomprehensible mess :( .

Comment: Ah, now I got it! 'swfobject.js' was the right keyword, as apparently a lot of people use it, so I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430508/swfobject-and-positioning

The solution is having the '< div id="game" >' encapsulate the '< div id="altContent" >' .

Comment: You are right, I saw that too, my mistake. I have edited my answer.